# Magento2 : Add Category Attribute Dropdown

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, category-attribute

I want to Create **Category Attribute** With Drop down
Drop down options are all list of **Product Attributes**
like http://prntscr.com/juglsn : 
I tried but it didn't works

`1.In setup file`

```
$eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'cat_attr1', [
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Attribute 1',
    'input' => 'select',
    'source' => 'Xx\Yy\Model\Config\Source\ProductAttributes',
    'required' => false,
    'sort_order' => 130,
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group' => 'Product Attribute Info',
    "default" => "",
    "class"    => "",
    "note"       => ""
]);
```

`2. In`category_form.xml`file`

```
<field name="cat_attr1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Xx\Yy\Model\Config\Source\ProductAttributes</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attribute 1</item>

            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
             <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

`3. in`ProductAttributes.php`file`

> namespace Xx\Yy\Model\Config\Source;

```
class ProductAttributes extends 
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    protected $productModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    )
    {
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
    }


    public function getAllOptions(){

     $productAttributes = $this->_productModel->getAttributes();  

     $productAttribute = [];
     foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {             
        $productAttribute[$attribute->getAttributeCode()]= $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
     }
      return $productAttribute;
    }

}
```

When I check In backend I show Loader only when  I Open category Tab

Comment: Where you want to display drop down ? Provide more details with question.

Comment: Those options static or dynamic?

Comment: I want to display option in category http://prntscr.com/jugv9a or with new tab

Comment: @Jeeva Chezhiyan yes all product attributes

Comment: You need to show all product attributes or especially the above attributes you mentioned?

Comment: @Jeeva Chezhiyan all product attributes

Comment: @ketan please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to customize convert the below functionality toOptionArray and add in Catalog Configuration.

**Vendor\Config\Model\Config\Source\ProductAttributes**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
)
{
    $this->_productModel = $productModel;
}

public function toOptionArray()
{

    $productAttributes = $this->_productModel->getAttributes(); 
    $productAttribute = [];
    foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {             
        $productAttribute[] = [ 'value' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'label' => $attribute->getFrontendLabel() ];
    }
    return $productAttribute;
}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_form.xml**

```
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="cat_prod_attr" sortOrder="40" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Product Attribute Name</label>                    
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ProductAttributes"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Hope this will help you

Comment: Check I have update question

Comment: I solved it.and used same way you did. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is seems to unclear to me.  But if you want to display Product attributes as **drop-down**.

Here i am assuming that you trying to display drop-down at admin.

You need to create a class that will return value like, `toOptionArray`.

Than you can use in your category's **`ui_component`** select field and than define options for that field like below.

```
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Attributes"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
```

> Block must have **toOptionArray** Method and it will return array same as class **`Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country`**.

Hope it will resolve you problem.

Comment: Check I have update question

Comment: Setup File i understand, But why you add source for block file. Like I've created boolean type attribute for category I used `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean`.

Comment: because I want all product attributr not boolean

Comment: Does your block file returns same array as i mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for customer ***dropdown***

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="seller_register_plan" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php


namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'seller_register_plan', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Seller Register Plan',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\SellerRegisterPlan',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'seller_register_plan')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

***This is the source Model***

> [VendorName][ModuleName]\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\SellerRegisterPlan.php

```
<?php


namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

class SellerRegisterPlan extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('Select an option')],
                ['value' => 'standard', 'label' => __('Standard')],
                ['value' => 'advanced', 'label' => __('Advanced')],
                ['value' => 'premium', 'label' => __('Premium')]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Let me know if face any issue....

Answer (score 0):

Use the code to get all the product attribute as dropdown
class AttSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

protected $collectionFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function toOptionArray(){

    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');
    $attributesArray = array();
    $attributesArray = array(
        array(
        'label' => __('None'),
        'value' => ''
        )
    );

    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $attribute) {
        $attributesArray[] = array('value'=> $attribute->getAttributeCode(),'label'=> $attribute->getFrontendLabel());
    }
    return $attributesArray;
}
```

}